# Does xoshiro/xoroshiro PRNGs provide uniform distribution?

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator

It's not clear from the [documentation](https://prng.di.unimi.it/) if the sequence of integers produced by these PRNGs belongs to the uniform distribution.

Also it's look like there is a whole family of RNG algorithms called in a similar manner. Personally I'm mostly interested in [`xoshiro256**`](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/a-quick-look-at-xoshiro256.html) - but no information about distribution uniformity as well.

Comment: I don't think xoroshiro&co aim to be cryptographically secure. So they're probably off-topic here.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks, but what forum would be appropriate for this question?

Comment: The llinked page has: _"they pass all tests we are aware of"_, in effect claiming uniform distribution for all practical purposes except cryptography.

Comment: The distribution is very close to uniform for example the 256 long generators run through all $2^{256}-1$ non-zero values of 256-bit words before cycling. As is commented above however, these are definitely not suitable for cryptography.